# Input.inputString but multiple button is pressed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, key-bindings

Ok so i want to create a keybind that can use all button input that unity support , but i don't want to create a loop that iterate trough all available `KeyCode` , nor do i want to create function that check if each `KeyCode` is pressed .

Then i found `Input.inputString` , exactly just like what i wanted , but `Input.inputString` is not an array, which only return 1 button even when i press multiple button.

So how do i get array version of Input.inputString ?

Comment: Normally you define keys in the input system so you can check "spell1" and whatever keycombo is assigned to that is what is needed to cause the match

Answer (score 0):

It already is enumerable since it is a string. Did you look at the documentation at all? This example is taken directly from the docs

```
foreach (char c in Input.inputString)
        {
            if (c == '\b') // has backspace/delete been pressed?
            {
                if (gt.text.Length != 0)
                {
                    gt.text = gt.text.Substring(0, gt.text.Length - 1);
                }
            }
            else if ((c == '\n') || (c == '\r')) // enter/return
            {
                print("User entered their name: " + gt.text);
            }
            else
            {
                gt.text += c;
            }
        }
```

Just modify to your requirements. I suspect though that this isn't *really* want to you want. If you can give more background to your situation I could give you a better answer